# Redefining SomeClass#each for just one instance

Tags: ruby

I have a method `f(x)`, where the only requirement to the argument `x` is that it implements the `each` method, which in turn in each iteration yields a string.

I can use `f` to produce the lines of a file by doing

```
myfile = File.open('....')
f(myfile)
myfile.close
```

Now comes the twist: `File#each` returns each line of the file including the newline, but I would like `f` to use the chomped lines of the file. I don't want to touch the implementation of `f`.

One solution would probably (I'm not sure whether this solution is sound with respect to the usage of `each`) be to subclass `File`:

```
class ChompingFile < File
  alias_method :file_each,:each
  def each
    file_each {|line| yield(line.chomp)}
  end
end

myfile = ChompingFile.open('....')
f(myfile)
myfile.close
```

But, can I do the same without subclassing, but with modifying the instance `myfile`? My first attempt was

```
myfile = File.open(.....)
myfile.alias_method(:file_each,:each) # DOES NOT WORK
def myfile.each
    file_each {|line| yield(line.chomp)}
end
f(myfile)
myfile.close
```

This gives an error, that `alias_method` is undefined. I think I can use it only if `self` is bound to a class, not to an instance.

Is it possible to achieve what I want? (And, is it wise to do so?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call just call `super`: (as [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35719331/redefining-someclasseach-for-just-one-instance#comment59120994_35719600) by Jörg W Mittag)

```
def myfile.each
  super { |line| yield(line.chomp) }
end
```

Example:

```
require 'stringio'
myfile = StringIO.new("foo\nbar\nbaz\n")

myfile.each { |line| p line }
#=> "foo\n"
#   "bar\n"
#   "baz\n"

def myfile.each
  super { |line| yield(line.chomp) }
end

myfile.rewind
myfile.each { |line| p line }
#=> "foo"
#   "bar"
#   "baz"
```

Answer (score 3):

This should do

```
myfile = File.open(.....)

class << myfile
    alias_method :file_each, :each

    def each
        file_each {|line| yield(line.chomp)}
    end
end
```

Comment: Why the `alias_method` dance? Why not just call `super`?